# What is the name of bar that contains hardware back button on android emulator and how to show it when it disappeared?

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

I am making a small app with React-Native.
Then when I navigate to the next page, the android bottom bar (contains hardware back button) disappears.
What is the name of this bar, and how to show it when it disappears?

> This is an inactive state.

[image]

> This is an active state.

[image]

How to show this bar? And how do we call this bar?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
I am answering my question.
The reason why the bar does not appear on the next page is that the page is a page that plays video or music. (uses react-native-video)
That's why it converted into a full-screen method.